# show always scrollbar

Tags: android, scrollbar, visibility

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
<Scrollview ...
```

i want to show the scrollbar always (`android:fadeScrollbars="false"`)! I have also EditTexts on my screen, too. That is why I put (`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` and `android:focusable="true"`). If i put this last 2 codes my scrollbar going to fade out, why? Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

please this in place of that one.

Achieved the desired result here and added in manifest for each activity

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"